# Convert column from str to datatime in excel whit openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, string, format, openpyxl

sorry for my English and explain easily please because I'm a super beginner... when I start to work with Python/pandas add a new column in my dataframe and then I convert it in datatime DBContratti["Data_scadenza"] = pd.to_datetime(DBContratti["Data_scadenza"])

After many steps, I exported my DB in Excel, and after this step started my problems because I wanted to compare the column "Data scadenza" with today's date, but the system tell me that this not is possible because I am trying to compare str and datatime. So I opened my Excel file and I can see that my format for this column in Excel is: "aaaa-mm-gg hh:mm:ss". My goal is to find some cells in Excel (with opnepyxl) with some conditions and change colors in these cells, but for me, this is not possible because cannot convert str with datatime.
This is the error:
time data 'Data_scadenza' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Help me, please!
Thanks
Chiara

```
#import module python
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import jinja2
import openpyxl
from stat import S_IREAD
from pandas import DataFrame
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from datetime import datetime



#IMPORT DB ARCHIVIO ANDATI, ARCHIVIO SCADUTI e CONTRATTI ATTIVI

Archivio_andati = pd.read_excel(r".\File_sistema\Archivio_andati.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col= None)

Archivio_scaduti = pd.read_excel(r".\File_sistema\Archivio_scaduti.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col= None)

Contratti_attivi = pd.read_excel(r".\File_sistema\Contratti_attivi.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col= None)

#IMPORT DBNomi e DBContratti
DBNomi = pd.read_excel(r".\File_gestione_orti\DB_Nomi.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col= None)

DBContratti = pd.read_excel(r".\File_gestione_orti\DB_Contratti.xlsx", sheet_name=0, index_col= None)

#import Anagrafe_Sicra.csv e convert in xlsx
DB_Sicra_IMPO = pd.read_csv(open(r".\File_sistema\grid_export.csv"), sep=",", index_col=None)
DB_Sicra_IMPO.to_excel(r".\File_sistema\grid_export.xlsx", index=None, header=True)

#rename columns 
DB_Sicra_IMPO.rename(columns={"per Anagrafe Unica Codice Fiscale":"Codice Fiscale", "aprFin Data Ini": "Data Cancellazione", "aprFin Motivo Des": "Motivo Cancellazione"}, inplace=True)

#select columns
DB_Sicra = DB_Sicra_IMPO[["Codice Fiscale", "Cognome", "Nome", "Data Nascita", "Indirizzo di residenza", "Comune di residenza", "Data Cancellazione", "Motivo Cancellazione"]]

#cast del DBNomi.xlsx
DBNomi["Cod_richiesta_ter_1"] = DBNomi["Cod_richiesta_ter_1"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Cod_richiesta_ter_2"] = DBNomi["Cod_richiesta_ter_2"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Codice Fiscale"] = DBNomi["Codice Fiscale"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Cognome e nome (A01)"] = DBNomi["Cognome e nome (A01)"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Telefono_casa"] = DBNomi["Telefono_casa"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Telefono_ufficio"] = DBNomi["Telefono_ufficio"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Cell_1"] = DBNomi["Cell_1"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Cell_2"] = DBNomi["Cell_2"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Email_1"] = DBNomi["Email_1"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Email_2"] = DBNomi["Email_2"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBNomi["Referente"] = DBNomi["Referente"].astype(object).astype(object)

#cast del DBContratti.xlsx
DBContratti["Codice_terreno"] = DBContratti["Codice_terreno"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Codice_appezzamento"] = DBContratti["Codice_appezzamento"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Tipologia Contratto"] = DBContratti["Tipologia Contratto"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Codice Fiscale"] = DBContratti["Codice Fiscale"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Cognome e nome (A02)"] = DBContratti["Cognome e nome (A02)"].astype(object).astype(object)
#trasforma la data di assegnazione in un campo datatime
DBContratti["Data_assegnazione"] = pd.to_datetime(DBContratti["Data_assegnazione"])
print (DBContratti["Data_assegnazione"] )

DBContratti["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"] = DBContratti["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].astype(object).astype(object)
#trasformare la data di contestazione in datatime
DBContratti["Data_contestazione_1"] = DBContratti["Data_contestazione_1"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Data_contastazione_2"] = DBContratti["Data_contastazione_2"].astype(object).astype(object)
DBContratti["Note"] = DBContratti["Note"].astype(object).astype(object)

#Add column Data Scadenza 
DBContratti.insert(6, "Data_scadenza", "")
DBContratti["Data_scadenza"] = pd.to_datetime(DBContratti["Data_scadenza"])

#variable whit date for P
DataPerenne = pd.to_datetime(["2033/12/31"])


#calculate date on the basis contract: 10 years for old contract, 8 years for new and use DataPerenne for type P
DBContratti["Data_scadenza"] = np.where(DBContratti["Tipologia Contratto"]=="V", DBContratti["Data_assegnazione"] + pd.DateOffset(years= 10),
                                        np.where(DBContratti["Tipologia Contratto"]=="N", DBContratti["Data_assegnazione"] + pd.DateOffset(years= 8), DataPerenne))


#merge between DBNomi e il DBContratti = M_DBNomiContratti
M_DBNomiContratti=DBNomi.merge(DBContratti, how="left", on="Codice Fiscale")

#merge between M_DBNomiContratti e DB_SIcra = M_DBKiara
M_DBKiara=M_DBNomiContratti.merge(DB_Sicra, how="left", on="Codice Fiscale")

#Erase columns ("Cognome e nome (a01)" del DBNomi e "Cognome e nome (a02)" del DBContratti) 
M_DBKiara.drop("Cognome e nome (A01)", inplace=True, axis=1)
M_DBKiara.drop("Cognome e nome (A02)", inplace=True, axis=1)

#New variable for calculate today date
data_ora = datetime.today()


#Create column contratto e insert data on the basesis data di scadenza and data di cessione
M_DBKiara["Contratto"] = np.where(M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"].isnull(), "Senza contratto",
                                    np.where((M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"] >= data_ora) & (M_DBKiara["Data Cancellazione"].notnull()) & M_DBKiara["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].isnull(), "Terminato per...",
                                    np.where((M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"]>=data_ora) & (M_DBKiara["Data Cancellazione"]).isnull() & M_DBKiara["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].isnull(), "Contratto attivo", "Contratto Terminato per scadenza o rinuncia/contestazione")))

#Move column CONTRATTO 
M_DBKiara.insert(15, "Contratto", M_DBKiara.pop("Contratto"))

#Create copy of M_DBKiara 
ArchivioAndati=pd.DataFrame()
ArchivioAndati = M_DBKiara[((M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"]>= data_ora) & (M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"].notnull())) & (M_DBKiara["Data Cancellazione"].notnull() | M_DBKiara["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].notnull())]

#Create copy of M_DBKiara 
ArchivioScaduti=pd.DataFrame()
ArchivioScaduti = M_DBKiara[((M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"]< data_ora) & (M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"].notnull())) & (M_DBKiara["Data Cancellazione"].isnull() & M_DBKiara["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].isnull())]

#Create copy of M_DBKiara 
ContrattiAttivi=pd.DataFrame()
ContrattiAttivi = M_DBKiara[((M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"]>= data_ora) & (M_DBKiara["Data_scadenza"].notnull())) & (M_DBKiara["Data Cancellazione"].isnull() & M_DBKiara["(R)inuncia-(C)ontestazione"].isnull())]

#Calcolate total rows in DB Archio_andati 
righe= len(Archivio_andati)

#Calcolate total rows in DB Archio_scaduti 
righe1= len(Archivio_scaduti)

#Calcolate total rows in DB Contratti_attivi 
righe2= len(Contratti_attivi)

#Add data to file Archivio_andati di xlsx 
with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\File_sistema\Archivio_andati.xlsx", mode="a", engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer: (ArchivioAndati.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Andati', startrow=righe+1, index=None, header=False))


#Add data to file Archivio_scaduti di xlsx
with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\File_sistema\Archivio_scaduti.xlsx", mode="a", engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer: (ArchivioScaduti.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Scaduti', startrow=righe1+1, index=None, header=False))

#Add data to file Contratti_attivi di xlsx 
with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\File_sistema\Contratti_attivi.xlsx", mode="a", engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists="replace") as writer: (ContrattiAttivi.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Attivi', index=None, header=True))

#Search the same rows in ArchivioAndati e DBContratti and erase
DBContratti=DBContratti[-DBContratti["Codice Fiscale"].isin(ArchivioAndati["Codice Fiscale"])]

#Search the same rows in ArchivioScaduti e DBContratti and erase  
DBContratti=DBContratti[-DBContratti["Codice Fiscale"].isin(ArchivioScaduti["Codice Fiscale"])]

#to empty ArchivioAndati 
ArchivioAndati=pd.DataFrame()

#to empty ArchivioScaduti 
ArchivioScaduti=pd.DataFrame()

#to empty ContrattiAttivi 
ContrattiAttivi=pd.DataFrame()

#Update file excel DB_contratti 
with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\File_gestione_orti\DB_contratti.xlsx", mode="w", engine='openpyxl') as writer: (DB_A02.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='DB_A02', index=None, header=True))

#Export merge table  in excel 
with pd.ExcelWriter(r".\File_gestione_orti\DB_finale.xlsx", mode="w", engine='openpyxl') as writer: (M_DBKiara.to_excel (writer, sheet_name='Tab_completa', index=None, header=True))

#make evident rows DI M_DBKiara with condiction on date field
#Import il file excel M_DBkiara
M_DBKiaraColor = openpyxl.load_workbook(".\File_gestione_orti\DB_finale.xlsx")

#Active sheet
foglio_attivo = M_DBKiaraColor.active

#Choose row
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00',
                   end_color='FFFF00',
                   fill_type='solid')

for v in (foglio_attivo['O']):
    if v.value!=None:
        if v.value!= datetime:
            v.value= datetime.strptime(v.value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

       

# Save file
M_DBKiaraColor.save(".\File_gestione_orti\DB_finale.xlsx")
```

I tried everything I also read the other posts, but nothing

Comment: Please provide some input [references/examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).


Also, read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

For your issue, you need to provide the correct format of date for `v.value`. Since you are getting a format error, there is a mismatch between the format of `v.value` and the format you provided to `strptime` but without any reference can't confirm anything.

Comment: The datas in column "O" in excel (the datas that I must convert) are so: 2033-12-31 00:00:00 but if I click into the cell, in the formula bar exit so: 31/12/2033  00:00:00. If I click right button mouse exit format custom aaaa-mm-gg hh:mm:ss

Comment: try to print `v.value` and share the parsed `str`.

Comment: IF REMOVE CONVERT
for v in (foglio_attivo['O']):
    if v.value!=None:
        if v.value!= datetime:
            print (v.value)

THIS IS RESULT:
Data_scadenza
2033-12-31 00:00:00
2028-05-02 00:00:00
2033-12-31 00:00:00
2025-11-09 00:00:00
2033-12-31 00:00:00
2031-02-11 00:00:00
2025-08-27 00:00:00
2025-11-09 00:00:00
2033-12-31 00:00:00
2033-12-31 00:00:00
2032-09-15 00:00:00

Process finished with exit code 0

The list was more long but all data as dates not cells empty or none or null

Comment: ` time data 'Data_scadenza' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`  this is trying to parse `Data_scadenza` as date which is not possible. Remove the column label.

After this, the date should parse correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.